# Decode mp4 to raw frames windows c++

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, mp4, libav

I'm trying to decode an MP4 file i've created using mp4creator library. I can't find a ffmpeg or libav example that actually works with the libraries, because the code is incompatible with the examples.

I need a simple way of reading the mp4 file and decoding it into raw audio and video frames. In needs to work on windows too.

If someone can point me towards a working and compatible ffmpeg/libav library + example source file that could work too.

If i could get the library version which was used in this tutorial that would work, since this guy seems to be the only one who wrote a decent tutorial on FFMPEG (albeit on some ancient version)
http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/

edit:

In the latest version of ffmpeg i found the example named: filtering_video.c
using a patch found: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-June/126587.html I have gotten the program to do "something" It looks to be working so I will investigate further.

Comment: If you can't find a library, I'd just use mp4box and call it from your code as you would in a command prompt.

Comment: I think ffmpeg can do that right out of the box: http://www.labnol.org/software/extract-image-frames-from-video/18137/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As edited into the question: In the latest version of ffmpeg i found the example named: filtering_video.c
using a patch found: http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2012-June/126587.html I have gotten the program to work.
Using the function avtoipl described here: http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/16949/6806/
I've gotten the data into an opencv RGB image which i can display.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? The link you provided isn't available anymore and I'm trying to solve the same problem as you did. Do you happen to have a code sample?

Comment: I'm sorry but this was 5 years ago and I do not have access to that code anymore. But only the second link is broken for me. The first (which fixed my actual problem) is not.